# Why is TSP 3-opt better than 2-opt?

Tags: combinatorics, optimization

For [Travelling salesman problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem), I've seen a couple of people claim that [3-opt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3-opt) yields a better solution than [2-opt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2-opt) (and 4-opt better than 3-opt, etc.) but I've never seen why and never seen any proof. It seems that 2-opt gives the same result as k-opt, k ≥ 2.

Do you have any counter-example? (preferably with images) I'd like ones that show 4-opt > 3-opt, 3-opt > 2-opt and 4-opt > 2-opt.

Comment: Related to your question: [Lin–Kernighan heuristic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lin%E2%80%93Kernighan_heuristic)